# Common method for comparing any two Java objects

Tags: java

I want to compare two Java objects **without overriding equals method**. Since I need to override equals method in n number of Classes I have, I am in need of a common utility method where we can compare two Java objects.

Something *like*:

```
A a1,a2;
B b1,b2;
C c1,c2;
-----
-----
boolean isEqual1 = new ObjectComparator().isEquals(a1 , a2);
boolean isEqual2 = new ObjectComparator().isEquals(b1 , b2);
boolean isEqual3 = new ObjectComparator().isEquals(c1 , c2);
```

Please help me out to write a common utility for comparing any Java objects

Hope by using `Field` class, and `getClass` method we can achieve it. Please guide me.

Comment: http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/reflectionassert/ReflectionComparator.html look at this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [`EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) in the Apache Commons library.

From the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> *This method uses reflection to determine **if the two Objects are equal**.*
>
> *It uses `AccessibleObject.setAccessible` to gain access to private fields. This means that it will throw a security exception if run under a security manager, if the permissions are not set up correctly. It is also not as efficient as testing explicitly.*

---

So, in your example it would look like:

```
A a1,a2;
B b1,b2;
C c1,c2;
-----
-----
boolean isEqual1 = EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(a1 , a2);
boolean isEqual2 = EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(b1 , b2);
boolean isEqual3 = EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(c1 , c2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That gave me a start. I need to customize that class to add certain features like, adding an exumption to a field from comparision etc. Will EqualsBuilder class helps me in achieving those features by extending that class?

Comment: WARNING: according to EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(Object lhs, Object rhs) Javadoc "Transient members will be not be tested". So i.e. EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(new Date(2), new Date(3)) will return true. Better use reflectionEquals(Object lhs, Object rhs, boolean testTransients).

Answer (score 4):

This may be what you are looking for [EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
}
```

Comment: *[...]without overriding the equals method[...]*  (+1 for anyway ;-)

Comment: Its an example from the doc which you can call without overriding. ;)

Comment: WARNING: according to EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(Object lhs, Object rhs) Javadoc "Transient members will be not be tested". So i.e. EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(new Date(2), new Date(3)) will return true. Better use reflectionEquals(Object lhs, Object rhs, boolean testTransients).

Answer (score 2):

Try Apache Commons [EqualsBuilder#reflectionEquals](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) method and check if it meets your needs.

Comment: WARNING: according to EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(Object lhs, Object rhs) Javadoc "Transient members will be not be tested". So i.e. EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(new Date(2), new Date(3)) will return true. Better use reflectionEquals(Object lhs, Object rhs, boolean testTransients).

Answer (score 1):

First, is there a compelling reason why you don't want to use the equals method? The equals method is used internally by collection classes and such so you will have to obey the equals contract.

If there is one, then yes, you can do a field by field comparison using reflection. 
Get the [list of fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html) of the class and for each field [check the value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html). You will also have to ensure that they are both instance of the same class upfront.

Comment: The compelling reason is my class may grow with more fields. each and every time i need to update equals method too.

Answer (score 0):

You want `Objects.equals(a,b)` available in Java 1.7, in the `java.util` package

If you are using a version earlier than Java 1.7, you can use one of the libraries that other people have suggested, most notably the Apache Commons project.

Comment: You mean here Objects.deepEquals(a, b). Objects.equals(a, b) just use the default equals() implementations of the objects, but can handle nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [Shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest).

From their github page:

> Having a `Person` bean with the following structure:
>
> ```
> Person person
>     |-- String name
>     |-- String surname
>     |-- Address address
>         |-- String streetName
>         |-- int streetNumber
>         |-- String postcode
> ```
>
> to compare two `Person` beans with Shazamcrest we would write:
>
> ```
> assertThat(actualPerson, sameBeanAs(expectedPerson));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This works perfectly but needs more heap space if the objects that you compares are huge. 
    org.unitils.reflectionassert.ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals(obj1, obj2)

http://www.unitils.org/

You can get the jar from below.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.unitils/unitils -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
          <artifactId>unitils</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>
```